# fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree

Tags: git, command-line

I get this error when I try to change branch.

Probably I will give some information of the commands at

```
/path/to/git/repo/.
```

upon command:

```
git branch
```

I get following output

```
* V1.5
  V2.0
  master
```

And when I try the command

```
git checkout V2.0
```

I get following output:

```
fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree
```

config file contents:

```
cat config 
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = /path/to/git/repo/.git
```

Comment: It seems you have a bare repo. Bare repos don't have a working tree, so `git checkout` doesn't make sense for them.

Answer (score 82):

You repository is bare, i.e. it does not have a working tree attached to it. You can clone it locally to create a working tree for it, or you could use one of several other options to tell Git where the working tree is, e.g. the `--work-tree` option for single commands, or the `GIT_WORK_TREE` environment variable. There is also the `core.worktree` configuration option but it will not work in a bare repository (check the man page for what it does).

```
# git --work-tree=/path/to/work/tree checkout master
# GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/to/work/tree git status
```

Comment: I have multiple working places through ssh and at the above give path I do not work. How can I give work-tree path then ?

Comment: Uhm… by using the `--work-tree` option, by setting the `GIT_WORK_TREE` environment variable, or by setting the `core.worktree` configuration option. I have a déjà vu.

Comment: Hmm, I just set core.bare to false, and lo and behold, it worked w/o --work-tree (which the docs say that if not given, git assumes you are in the top of the tree.)

Comment: the working tree must exist, otherwise it fails

Comment: My downvote was for telling us /what/ we can do, but not /how/ to do it. Git is notoriously ornery for occasional users, and we come to s/o looking for how.

Comment: when config contains `core.bare = true` and `core.worktree = "/path/to/worktree/"`, doing a `git checkout branch` says `fatal: core.bare and core.worktree do not make sense`. Hence, have to set `core.bare = false` as well. Then it worked.

Comment: Instructions are not clear enough.

Comment: Where the hell is the worktree?

Comment: I know this is an old thread but for me the issue was that I was in the .git sub directory. Once I cd'ed out of it, everything worked fine.

Comment: @JonnyCerveza Please add your comment as an answer -- this was the solution for me as well.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks these solutions don't work with `gitk`.

Comment: My problem was that I had cloned to one place, and it had put the absolute path to that place in `.git/config`, but I subsequently moved the whole repo one folder up, and Git didn't like that. Fixing the path in `.git/config` resolved my problem.

Comment: @underscore_d  I had the same problem and fixing the path in .git/config solved the problem.

Comment: This error can also show up when there are other '.git' folders in any sub directories.

Comment: @JonnyCerveza I owe you a cerveza!! Should be accepted anser FOR SURE

Comment: run `git config core.bare false` to update the `.git/config` file

Comment: @JonnyCerveza Please set this as an alternative answer, I had the same thing happening