# How do I get my files uploaded with post-receive?

Tags: git, git-post-receive

I have the following shell script as `post-receive` hook, which should copy my working copy into my `/mnt/repo/` folder:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
rm -rf /tmp/repo/
rm -rf /mnt/repo/*

mkdir /tmp/repo/ && cd /tmp/repo/

git init
git remote add origin file:///home/git/repos/repo.git
git fetch
git checkout development

cp -r /tmp/repo/* /mnt/repo/
```

If I run it locally, it works just fine. However, if it is run by Git after pushing, it won't work, and I get the following output in my local Git Bash:

```sh
$ git push local development
git@192.168.178.88's password:
Counting objects: 6, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 349 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/repo/
remote: From file:///home/git/repos/repo
remote:  * [new branch]      development -> origin/development
remote:  * [new branch]      release    -> origin/release
remote: fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree
To git@192.168.178.88:repos/repo.git
   01568cc..ee31229  development -> development
```

Moreover, in my `/tmp/repo` and `/mnt/repo` folders, I have the following folder structure:

```
drwxr-xr-x  7 git  git  220 Mar 14 13:47 .
drwxrwxrwt  3 root root  60 Mar 14 13:47 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 git  git   40 Mar 14 13:47 branches
-rw-r--r--  1 git  git  183 Mar 14 13:47 config
-rw-r--r--  1 git  git   73 Mar 14 13:47 description
-rw-r--r--  1 git  git  240 Mar 14 13:47 FETCH_HEAD
-rw-r--r--  1 git  git   23 Mar 14 13:47 HEAD
drwxr-xr-x  2 git  git  200 Mar 14 13:47 hooks
drwxr-xr-x  2 git  git   60 Mar 14 13:47 info
drwxr-xr-x 44 git  git  880 Mar 14 13:47 objects
drwxr-xr-x  5 git  git  100 Mar 14 13:47 refs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a new repository and hence a working tree has yet not been attached to it.

[Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262801/fatal-this-operation-must-be-run-in-a-work-tree) for more details.