# Git Command Execution Error: fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree

Tags: git

I got this error while executing git commands in a repo.

```
fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree
```

Also being asked: [fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262801/fatal-this-operation-must-be-run-in-a-work-tree)

Answer (score -2):

I found that that my core.bare flag is set as true. Setting it to false, resolves the issue

```
git config core.bare false
```