# Stuck in Detached HEAD on git

Tags: git, github

I'm stuck in "Detached HEAD" on git. I got there by reverting back to a previous commit. And now that I've made changes, I'd like tried to commit them but realised I couldn't because I'm in the detactched head thing.

I've tried using `git checkout main` but that gives me `fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree`. And I can't seem to find a working solution for that either. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you inside a bare repo?

Comment: No. At least I shouldn't be. When I reverted back to a previous commit I use `git checkout {commit}`. So unless that puts you into one, then no

Comment: You might be inside the `.git` folder?

Comment: Just fyi, I usually work out of the github desktop client. So, I'm not too familiar with the commands

Comment: How would I know if I'm in there?

Comment: If you're using linux/mac type `pwd` or `echo %cd%` on windows. Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262801/fatal-this-operation-must-be-run-in-a-work-tree or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456923/why-am-i-getting-the-message-fatal-this-operation-must-be-run-in-a-work-tree help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251357/discussion-between-matt-cole-and-evolutionxbox).